# New variable for missing values across multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to see if R has a command similar to Stata. In Stata, the !mi(a, b, c,...) command creates a new variable and indicates a 1/0 if the indicated variable(s) have no missing data. 1 = no missing data across variables x, 0 = missing data in one of the variables x.

I'm looking for a simple code because sometimes I have about 15-20 variables (mainly to mark listwise deletion cases). It takes a little more work but I specify the column names instead of using the : marker. The options I've found creates a new dataframe (na.omit), but I want to retain all the cases.

I know that ifelse can accomplish this using:

```
df$test <- ifelse(!is.na(df$ID) & !is.na(df$STATUS), 1,0)
```

I like to know if there's another way with less code where I don't need to write "!is.na(df$ )" over and over. Maybe a $global code (similar to Stata)?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this using `complete.cases`

```
df$test <- as.numeric(complete.cases(df))
```

Comment: And you can specify certain columns by picking them out of `df`: `as.numeric(complete.cases(df[, c("a", "b", "d")])`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `rowSums`:

```
df$test <- as.numeric(rowSums(is.na(df)) == 0)
```